# Convert numpy array with values into array with frequency for each observation in each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
array = np.random.randint(6, size=(50, 400))
```

This array has the cluster that each value belongs to, with each row representing a sample and each column representing a feature, but I would like to create a 5 dimensional array with the frequency of each cluster (in each sample, represented as a row in this matrix).

However, in the frequency calculation, I want to ignore 0, meaning that the frequency of all values except 0 (1-5) should add to 1.

Essentially what I want is a array with each row being a cluster (1-5) in this case, and each row still contains a single sample.

How can this be done?

Edit:

small input:

```
input = np.random.randint(6, size=(2, 5))

array([[0, 4, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 5, 2, 5, 3]])
```

output:

```
1    2    3    4    5

0   .33  .33  .33   0
0   .2   .2    0   .6
```

Where 1-5 are the row names, and the bottom two rows are the desired output in a numpy array.

Comment: Can you show an example small input and desired output?

Comment: When you say "5 dimensional array" do you mean an array of shape `(5,)`?

Comment: I just added an example input and output. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple application of bincount. Does this do what you want?

```
def freqs(x):
    counts = np.bincount(x, minlength=6)[1:]
    return counts/counts.sum()

frequencies = np.apply_along_axis(freqs, axis=1, arr=array)
```

If you were wondering about the speed implications of `apply_along_axis`, this method using tricky indexing is marginally slower in my tests:

```
counts = (array[:, :, None] == values[None, None, :]).sum(axis=1)
frequencies2 = counts/counts.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `axis=1` and no `.T`?

Comment: @filippo indeed. Thanks.